# Dropdown menu not working in desktop mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on the CSS dropdown below. It is working fine for the mobile version but for the desktop version it is creating a problem.

```
<div class="container"> 
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home"><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Learn Education" title="Learn Education"/></a></div>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-7 pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="border:none;border-radius:15px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right changeme" id="visibid">
                <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">LogIn</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">SignUp</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Sample Test <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Mathematics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Physics</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Chemistry</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">DashBoard</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Here is the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/c7D8XTIftlwGCkwfBzYb?p=preview).

In order to see the error please switch to fullscreen mode and press any of those buttons.

Comment: Can you describe your problem more clearly? What do you expect to see? When I click the button, a menu appears

Comment: can U switch to full screen on plunker and press any button then u can see it Press on login or signup or home

Comment: Is it ok if to fix it you have to remove bootstrap collapse, and include jquery slideToggle. I can help you it fix in this way.

Comment: Sorry @A.J I dont know jquery can u say what is the problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add media queries

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
      display:none;
  }        
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse"` from all the links - this is causing the Bootstrap JS to try and collapse the menu

Comment: But without that the dropdown is not closing when I click on any button